# Ayuda para Compilar

Tags: java

¿Se puede compilar en un proyecto java(Maven, jetty) solo los cambios realizados desde la ultima compilación para no perder mucho tiempo en compilar por solo realizar un pequeño cambio?

Answer (score -1):

Hasta donde yo sé, si utilizas una herramienta de compilación (ant, maven, gradle, make...) Sólo se compilan los archivos que se han modificado desde la última vez que se realizó una compilación, la única excepción sería cuando se hace un 'clean' a todo el proyecto